# Android Studio - ошибка Failed to resolve

Tags: android, gradle

В Android Studio после запуска появляется ошибка в build.gradle

```
C:\Android\AndroidLessons\AndroidLessons\app\build.gradle
Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2
Error:(27, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2
<a href="install.m2.repo">Install Repository and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile:C:/Android/AndroidLessons/AndroidLessons/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

В build.gradle следуещее:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Когда нажимаю ***Install Repository and sync project*** появляется ошибка ***All packages are not available to for doenload!***

[image: скриншот]

Comment: build.gradle какая версия?

Comment: compileSdkVersion 26

Comment: buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

Comment: В build.gradle (Project) гляньте

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1' - вот так выглядит строка, номер может быть другой

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

Comment: поменяйте на 3.0.1 и нажмите sync now. Вверху появится желтая полоса

Comment: На желтой полосе ошибка Gradle sync failed.... и есть Try again. Нажимаю - выдает Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1

Comment: File -> Setting -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle -> Use default gradle wrapper установите

Comment: File -> Project Structure -> Project установите gradle version 4.1 и android plugin version 3.0.1 если android studio 3

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить строку

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
```

на

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
```

Если не поможет, перенесите строки

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

в build.gradle модуля app таким образом:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю под "перенести" заменить compile на implementation или нет? Пишет Gradle DSL method not found: 'implementation()'

Comment: да. заменить compile на implementation. Но именно в build.gradle модуля, а не проекта. В build.gradle проекта - удалить